# How to run ranlib on an archive built through Android.mk?

Tags: android, android-ndk, archive, one-definition-rule

This has come up on a couple of libraries I work with regularly. See, for example:

- [Error SSL archive symbol table (run ranlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36324125)
- [no archive symbol table (run ranlib) while building libcryptopp.a through ndk-build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34043538)

In the questions, the users created an Android.mk for the OpenSSL and Crypto++ libraries. The pain point seems to be users adding the Android.mk wrapper to the sources.

Outside of Android, each project is Makefile based, each project builds a static archive, and each project builds a shared object based on the static archive. Each project also runs `ranlib` on the static archive. Crypto++ is especially sensitive to the need for `ranlib` because its a C++ library and [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) violations lead to undefined behavior.

When using Android.mk to build a static archive, how do we run ranlib on an archive through Android.mk?

Answer (score 2):

I was running into similar issues and found a command on [this website](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android#Install_the_OpenSSL_Library) which fixed it for me

```
# The -E is important. Root needs some of the user's environment
$ sudo -E make install CC=$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc RANLIB=$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe the command you showed uses OpenSSL makefile. This question is trying to determine how to have `Android.mk` run `ranlib` on the archive at build time. I also believe the OpenSSL makefile is broken in that it runs `ranlib` during install instead of a regular `make [all]` (or some other target). Make is not supposed to build components during `install` target.